Enable both system-assigned and user assigned identities to Azure Virtual Machine simultaneously in single REST API call
I'm attempting to configure an Azure Virtual Machine (VM) to have both a system assigned managed identity (MSI) and a user assigned managed identity using REST API calls. While I've been able to enable one or the other using PowerShell, I'm struggling to find documentation or examples on how to enable both simultaneously via REST API.
Here's the PowerShell code I've tried so far:

Enabling system assigned managed identity:
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VM $vm -IdentityType SystemAssigned

Assigning user assigned managed identity:
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VM $vm -IdentityType UserAssigned -IdentityID "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourcegroups/<RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<USER ASSIGNED IDENTITY NAME>"


While these PowerShell commands work individually, I'm having trouble combining them to enable both types of managed identities for the Azure VM.
Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this using REST API calls? Specifically, I'm looking for the equivalent REST API requests to achieve the configurations mentioned above.
I already have a service principal with clientId, secret, and tenant to create a OAuth2 token, and it has the necessary contributor role under the subscription.

Initially, I generated one bearer token for service principal having "Contributor" role under subscription via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default

Response:

To enable both system-assigned and user assigned identities to Azure Virtual Machine simultaneously, make use of below API call:
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM?api-version=2017-12-01 HTTP/1.1
{
    "identity":{
       "type":"SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
       "identityIds":[
          "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/ID1"
       ]
    }
 }

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, both identities enabled successfully in virtual machine as below:


Reference:
Configure managed identities on Azure VM using REST | Microsoft

Sridevi, huge thanks for your response and reference document. It did the trick!

Yes it solved my initial requirement. My next step is to replicate this process in PowerShell using Invoke-RestMethod @Sridevi can you please assist with that PS script?

@Dhivyesh Please post a new question with more details regarding your requirement and add that question link here.

New post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78434341/replicate-azure-virtual-machine-managed-identity-configuration-rest-api-with-pow Please assist @Sridevi
