Replicate Azure Virtual Machine Managed Identity configuration REST API with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod
I recently received helpful guidance on enabling both system-assigned
and user-assigned managed identities for an Azure Virtual Machine (VM)
through REST API calls. Now, I'm seeking assistance to replicate this process using PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod.
Here's the REST API call I used to achieve this:
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION
ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE
GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VM
NAME>?api-version=2017-12-01 HTTP/1.1 
{
    "identity":{
       "type":"SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
       "identityIds":[
          "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourcegroups/<RESOURCE
GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<USER
ASSIGNED IDENTITY NAME>"
       ]
    }
}

Could someone assist me in translating this into a PowerShell script
using Invoke-RestMethod? Specifically, I need guidance on how to
incorporate the authentication using a service principal, constructing
the JSON payload, and making the PATCH request.
Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can make use of below PowerShell script to enable both identities by calling REST API with Invoke-RestMethod:
# Authentication
$tenantId = "tenantId"
$clientId = "appId"
$clientSecret = "secret"
$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"

$body = @{
    "grant_type"    = "client_credentials"
    "client_id"     = $clientId
    "client_secret" = $clientSecret
    "resource"      = "https://management.azure.com/"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Body $body
$accessToken = $response.access_token

# Define variables
$subscriptionId = "subId"
$resourceGroup = "Sri"
$vmName = "testvm"
$userAssignedIdentityName = "testusermi"
$apiVersion = "2017-12-01"

# Construct JSON payload
$jsonPayload = @{
    "identity" = @{
        "type" = "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned"
        "identityIds" = @(
            "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/$userAssignedIdentityName"
        )
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Construct PATCH URL with formatted vmName 
$patchUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{0}?api-version=$apiVersion" -f $vmName

# PATCH request
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $patchUrl -Headers @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
} -Body $jsonPayload

$result

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, both identities enabled successfully in Azure virtual machine as below:
System assigned managed identity:

User assigned managed identity:

